# Delphi FMX: How to add an Event into an object (just like TEdit.OnChange)

Tags: oop, delphi, events, firemonkey

Assume I have created a new FMX project with nothing more than a TButton and a TProgressBar on it. 
Now I added a 'Countertest.pas' file using [Shift] + [F11]. (see code below)

Now I have implemented a procedure into 'Unit1.pas' (the main app) to be triggered by a procedure inside the 'Countertest.pas' file to change the Value of the TProgressBar.

Inside 'Unit1.pas' I wrote this to be called from inside the 'Countertest.pas' file:

```
procedure TForm1.SomethingChanged(newPercentage:Integer);
begin
ProgressBar1.Value:=newPercentage;
showmessage('Congratulations, you have just reached '+IntToStr(newPercentage)+' Percent ;)');
end;
```

To simplify my problem, this is my stripped down 'Countertest.pas' file:

```
unit Countertest;

interface

uses FMX.Memo; // Will be used later

type
  TCountertest = Class
  private
    zahl: Integer;
  published
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy();
    procedure Counter();
    property Percentage: Integer read zahl;
  end;

implementation

constructor TCountertest.Create();
begin

end;

destructor TCountertest.Destroy();
begin

end;

procedure TCountertest.Counter();
begin
  for i := 0 to 1337 do
  Percentage:=0;
  begin
    zahl:=i;
    if Percentage<>round(i / 100) then 
    begin
        // Here I want to call a Procedure inside 'Unit1.pas' to change a Value of the TProgressBar (and some other components like TLabel.Text)
    end;
    Percentage:=round(i / 100);
  end;
end;

end.
```

As far as I know there is the possibility to use something like `procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;` and it seems to be the thing a want to use, however I don't have any idea of how to use this.
My Intention is to write something similar to an OnChange Event used in a TEdit Control.

Of Course I could add 'Unit1.pas' into the Uses section of 'Countertest.pas' and then call the procedure directly, but as have to handle multiple Instances of TCountertest, I want to have it more like this:

```
procedure InstanceOfTCountertest.SomethingChanged(newPercentage:Integer);
begin
ProgressBar1.Value:=newPercentage;
showmessage('Congratulations, you have just reached a new Percent ;)');
end;
```

In the final app there are multiple Instances of TCountertest, so I have multiple Progressbars as well (and other GUI components such as TLabels).
Maybe there are other ways to do this, so feel free to suggest anything, that could fit the purpose to show the Progress of those Instances.

Comment: Did you consider looking at the FMX or VCL source code to see how events  (like TEdit.OnChange) are done? You have the source available in most Delphi SKUs.

Comment: Yes, I tried to look, what the TEdit Control does, but that didn't help me, because I didn't fully understand, how that works. At the moment I have a workaround: I pass the ProgressBar through the Parameters of the constructor into a private variable inside the object, so I can make changes to the Value Property of the ProgressBar inside my object.
I think this should work well enough for me, but I am still interested in how to do such a thing like a real OnChange Procedure is created each Time I create a new Instance of the object (like an Onchange Element of a TEdit Control)

Comment: An Edit Control has the property OnChange and a function with the return type TNotifyEvent with the result beeing  Model.OnChange. The Model itself uses 'procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;'. I've tried to implement this into my object, but I failed, because no matter, where I placed those things, there were always errors saying one Element is not declared.

Comment: Trace through the code further (or look at the VCL code, which is easier to follow). You'll see that you'll find a `DoChange` method that checks to see if there's an event handler assigned to `OnChange`, and if so calls it. Your code should do the same. The procedure can call the event handler with whatever parameters you choose to write it to receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, components (like `TButton` for example) expose events as properties (eg.: `TButton.OnCLick`) and it's up to the parent or sibling components (the parent `TForm` in this case) to set the event handler. Let's say we want to change the `Button1.OnClick` event handler:

```
// Setting the handler:

procedure TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    Button1.OnClick := Self.MyCustomClickHandler;
end;

// And the handler implementation:

procedure TForm1.MyCustomClickHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
    // ...
end;
```

So, I imagine you want to have an event for your `TCountertest` like `TCountertest.OnCount` so that other components / forms can set a handler and act in response to a change in your counter's progress. Let's describe how to do it the Delphi way (untested code):

First, your component should implement and expose the event:

```
unit Countertest;

interface

type
    // Custom type for your event handler
    TCountEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Percentage: Integer) of object;

    TCountertest = Class
    private
        FPercentage: Integer;

        // Variable that holds the event handler set by the user
        FOnCount: TCountEvent;

        // Internal event trigger
        procedure DoCount();

    public
        constructor Create();
        destructor Destroy();
        procedure Counter();

    published
        property Percentage: Integer read FPercentage;

        // This is the property for your event handler assignment
        property OnCount: TCountEvent read FOnCount write FOnCount;
    end;

implementation

constructor TCountertest.Create();
begin
    // Initialize event handler to nil
    FOnCount := nil;
end;

destructor TCountertest.Destroy();
begin
end;

// Event trigger
procedure TCounterTest.DoCount();
begin
    // Check that the user assigned an event handler
    if Assigned(FOnCount) then
        FOnCount(Self, FPercentage);
end;

procedure TCountertest.Counter();
begin
    // Your code (update FPercentage in your code)...

    // When you need to trigger the event:
    DoCount();

    // Rest of your code...
end;

end.
```

Now we are ready to create and set event handlers to your instances of `TCountertest`:

```
unit Unit1;

// ...

type
    TForm1 = class
    private
        // ...

        // Declare the handler
        procedure CounterCount(Sender: TObject; Percentage: Integer);
    public
        // ...
    end;

implementation

// ...

// Implement the handler
procedure TForm1.CounterCount(Sender: TObject; Percentage: Integer);
begin
    ProgressBar1.Value := Percentage;
end;

// Set the event handlers for your counters
procedure TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
    Counter1, Counter2: TCountertest;
begin
    // Create the counters
    Counter1 := TCountertest.Create();
    Counter2 := TCountertest.Create();

    // Set the event handlers
    Counter1.OnCount := Self.CounterCount;
    Counter2.OnCount := Self.CounterCount;
end;

end.
```

I hope it helps. Feel free to ask if not.

Comment: "Of course, for a `TButton`, we don't need to set it because the VCL already does". What do you mean with that?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I meant that for `TButton` we don't need to code the event handler for ``OnClick`` and set it because the IDE does it automatically, but I realized it was unnecessary. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @karliwson: The answer you provided worked fine for Counter1, but on my Form1 I create a new TProgressBar for each TCountertest I create, so how do I actually tell the TForm1.CounterCount to use ProgressBar1 for Counter1 and ProgressBar2 for Counter2 etc.? I assume I have to add a new Variable into the Countertest object, which will be initiated somewhere in the type section and will be increased on each Create() event. Possibly I could iterate through a for loop in the CounterCount procedure to set the percentage for each Progressbar, but that seems to be odd to me somehow. So how do I do it?

Comment: Also I am curious, whether it's possible to automatically let the IDE create a new Method based on just using (creating) an object analogue to the TButton.OnClick Event.

Comment: @qGold, you need to identify your counters somehow. You can put a parameter in the constructor of `TCountertest`, maybe an integer to serve as an ID, and a property to access that ID, let's say `TCounterTest.ID`, then you'd know which counter triggered the event by checking `TCountertest(Sender).ID`.

Comment: If you want the IDE to generate and set event handlers like it does with `TButton.OnClick` or `TTimer.OnTimer` you need to create a component. For now your `TCountertest` is just a class.

Comment: That's what I tried to mention above, but my problem is, that I don't know, where I have to declare the ID property to be used for the whole class and not just an instance of my class. What I've tried: I put an Int variable directly below the line containing 'type' and then tried to do `FInstanceCounter:=FInstanceCounter+1;` in the Create() but obviously that didn't work. _Sorry for this stupid question, but I'm new to oop in Delphi._
Ah, thanks, I'll make it a component later, if the other things are working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153912/discussion-between-karliwson-and-qgold).